# How to drag an element and drop it in another frame?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

Hope you doing well,

I'm trying to dragAndDrop an element from FrameOne to FrameTwo but not able to do so.Please help me to understand the concept and what I'm doing wrong here and need to achieve the task by using Actions class only.

Here're the URLs :

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
Here the element is in a div block I'm able to get all the locaters and do all other actions using Actions class but not able to drag and drop the element.

2.https://codepen.io/rjsmer/full/vvewWp

Here I'm trying to move the element from Frame one to Frame two but I'm not able to do so.

I've tried `dragAndDrop()`,`ClickAndHold()` methods,Searched so many solutions, watch videos on the same with no success.

```
package DragAndDropPracticeFrame;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import static io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.DriverManagerType.CHROME;

public class DragDropFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://codepen.io/rjsmer/full/vvewWp");
    driver.switchTo().frame("result");
    System.out.println("Inside First Frame.");
    WebElement frameOne =         
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.dragFrame.dragDrop"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(frameOne);
    System.out.println("Inside Frame 3");
    WebElement elementOne = driver.findElement(By.id("dragFrame-0"));
    System.out.println("First element found: " + elementOne.getText());
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    System.out.println("Inside main page");
    driver.switchTo().frame("result");
    //System.out.println("Switched to Frame First");
    WebElement frameThree = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='dropFrame dragDrop']"));
    Action action =
    builder.clickAndHold(elementOne)
    .moveToElement(frameThree)
    .release(frameThree).build();

    //driver.switchTo().frame(frameTwo);
    //System.out.println("Switched to frame 3");
    action.perform();

    //driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    //builder.perform();

}
}
```

Another try :

```
WebDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://codepen.io/rjsmer/full/vvewWp");
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        WebElement frameOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='dragFrame dragDrop']"));
        WebElement frameTwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='dropFrame dragDrop']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frameOne);
// identify element in first frame
        WebElement elementOne = driver.findElement(By.id("dragFrame-0"));

// Use Actions class for tap and hold
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        Actions action = actions.clickAndHold(elementOne);
        actions.build();
        action.perform();

// switch to the second frame
        driver.switchTo().frame(frameTwo);

// move element to another frame
        WebElement elementTwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@class='frameBody dropFrameBody']"));
        Actions actions2 = new Actions(driver);
        Actions action2 = actions2.moveToElement(elementTwo);
        actions2.release(elementOne);
        actions2.build();
        action2.perform();
```

Expected: The element should move to Frame 3 Actual: Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

try this out
Create object of actions class

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
```

Find element xpath which we need to drag

```
WebElement drag=driver.findElement(By.xpath("put x path"));
```

Find element xpath where we need to drop

```
WebElement drop=driver.findElement(By.xpath("put x path"));
```

Drag element to destination

```
act.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();
```

To use drag and drop in CQ use double click function first and put any component then try above method.

update

```
int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
               //do somthing
        } 
        catch(StaleElementException e) {
        }
        attempts++;
    }
```

Comment: Hi rao, I tried it's holding the element but not droping it in frame. getting following exception : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: okay then your frame is either not available or not clickable

Comment: so what you keep your drop function in for loop and try to drop

Comment: builder.doubleClick(frameOne).build().perform();
        builder.moveToElement(elementToDrag).clickAndHold().build().perform();
        builder.doubleClick(frameTwo).build().perform();
        WebElement elementTwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@class='frameBody dropFrameBody']"));
        builder.release(elementTwo).build().perform();

Comment: Even after I'm switching to frame I'm not able to do so can you check the code on your end?

Comment: Do you know what StaleElementReference exception is ?

Comment: Yes , it means the element is removed or not attached to the DOM this is what I know.I'm new to selenium.

Comment: okay so issue is cleared maybe the frame is not available to `DOM` then how you can drop or cross check your `DOM` for both Frame's availablity

Comment: Frame is there you can check the second URL in OP. I'm just not able to find the way to drop it.

Comment: [refer this solution](https://www.guru99.com/drag-drop-selenium.html)

Comment: This one is pretty basic, I'm able to drag and drop elements on these kinds of pages.My problem is bit different there are total three frame first I need to go to first frame then inside frame two here I need to drag element then I've to go to frame 3 here I need to drop the element (Before moving to frame three, First I've to switch to default content then frame 1 ).

Answer (score 0):

Below Code worked for me. But not sure how much is feasible.(for different `browsers/resolutions/devices`) I tried it on chrome browser and it worked for me.

```
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        System.out.println("switched to frame-0");
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement elementOne = driver.findElement(By.id("dragFrame-0"));
        builder.clickAndHold(elementOne);
        builder.moveToElement(elementOne, 10, 10);
        Action action = builder.build();
        action.perform();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        System.out.println("switched to default content");

        driver.switchTo().frame("result");
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        System.out.println("switched to frame-1");
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@class='frameBody dropFrameBody']"));
        System.out.println("element found");
        builder.moveToElement(ele).click(ele).release(ele);
        System.out.println("element released");
        builder.release(ele);
        action = builder.build();
        action.perform();
        WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@class='frameBody dropFrameBody']/ul/li[@id='dragFrame-0']"));
        boolean b = ele2.isDisplayed();
        System.out.println(b);
        Thread.sleep(6000);
```